# AudioToolbox symbol not found when running mame64 on OS X Mojave

Tags: emulation, macos-mojave, audiotoolbox

Earlier builds of Mame 0.205 run fine, but now when I build Mame 0.211 I get this error message:

```
./mame64
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZTINSt3__112bad_weak_ptrE
  Referenced from: /Users/myself/mame/m06/./mame64
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
 in /Users/myself/mame/m06/./mame64
Abort trap: 6
```

I'm running OS X Mojave 10.14.5 on a MacBook Pro.

Do I have a bad install of AudioToolbox, or some other problem?